# How to get the column name of max value in data fame python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to get the column name of the max value of each row.

```
            S1        S2       S3      S4 
Con1  -0.166277  0.329279  5.4941  3.6587
Con2  -0.015557  0.063506  6.5012 -2.6939
Con3  -0.230677  0.525414  7.2712  8.8743
Con4  -0.155739  0.335635 -6.2533 -4.6159
```

when I use df.idxmax(axis=1) it shown below.

```
Con1      S1 
Con2      S1 
Con3      S4 
Con4      S2
```

```
maxdf = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

expected result:

```
S1: {Con1,Con2,}
S2: {Con4}
S3: {}
S4: {Con3}
```

Comment: How working my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and aggregate `set`s, last add missing values by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
maxdf = df.idxmax(axis=1)
print (maxdf)
Con1    S3
Con2    S3
Con3    S4
Con4    S2
dtype: object

s =  maxdf.reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].apply(set).reindex(df.columns, fill_value={})
print (s)
S1              {}
S2          {Con4}
S3    {Con2, Con1}
S4          {Con3}
Name: index, dtype: object
```

If want lists in output use:

```
s =  maxdf.reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].apply(list).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=[])
print (s)
S1              []
S2          [Con4]
S3    [Con1, Con2]
S4          [Con3]
Name: index, dtype: object
```